# Why does a packed Perl script not work on a different machine?

Tags: perl

I have been trying to compile a script that was written in perl by someone other than myself into an executable format that can be used without having perl installed. There seems to be some sort of issue with `Crypt::SSLeay` packaging but I'm not sure what the error means. Here is a [screenshot of the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g3FBM.png).

I've tried using PAR `pp` and `cava` to package, both will create executables that run just fine on the machine I'm using that has perl, but whenever I transfer it to a different computer I get the error seen in the screenshot. It's been the same error each time after changing compiler settings, and I'm not sure what to do at this point. If I have left anything out that may assist in answer please let me know and I will be happy to provide, coding is not my field so I am still learning and this is my first encounter with Perl.

Comment: using `pp`, I've sometimes had to explicitly include modules in the command i.e. `pp -M Crypt::SSLeay -o script.exe script.pl` not sure why that is, but can't hurt to try

Comment: I suspect SSLeay.dll depends on an openssl dll; maybe see what `dumpbin /dependents SSLeay.dll` says on your system?

Comment: here's someone who got it working, albeit 13 years ago: http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=972688

Comment: Please don't show us images of text. How is that supposed to be useful? Your error messages are text - so why not just include the text in your question?

Answer (score 2):

First off, [you probably do not need and should not use Crypt::SSLeay](https://metacpan.org/pod/Crypt::SSLeay#DO-YOU-NEED-Crypt::SSLeay?). However, both the modern [Net::SSLeay](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::SSLeay) and `Crypt::SSLeay` require [OpenSSL](https://www.openssl.org/) binaries to be installed on the machine to run.

> both will create executables that run just fine on the machine I'm using that has perl, but whenever I transfer it to a different computer I get the error ...

That's because the target machine does not have `OpenSSL` installed in the same location on which compiled the modules you are bundling.